# Are Queen Lurline and Queen Zurline the same person?

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz, life-adventures-santa-claus

Are Queen Lurline and Queen Zurline in the Oz books the same person?

Comment: Related, not dupe; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172321/are-queen-lulea-and-queen-lurline-the-same-character

Comment: Per wiki; "*In Baum's book, The Life and Adventures of Santa Claus, the Queen of the Fairies is unnamed, and the Queen of the Wood Nymphs is named Zurline. Some debate exists among fans of the Oz books as to whether the unnamed Fairy Queen and Lurline are the same person. Queen Zixi of Ix depicts another Fairy Queen named Lulea, who is based in the Forest of Burzee, just as The Fairy Queen and Queen Zurline of the Wood Nymphs are.*" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Lurline